# How to filter required lines from following input file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

**Input Data**

```
%                Job1      EXEC +10 03:28 (03:23)  #J18911
                 Job2      EXEC +10 12:56 (01:55)  #J1766
                 Job3      EXEC +10 04/05          #J333460
                 Job4      EXEC +10 02/26 (01:10)  #J3322
>>every run      Job5      EXEC +10 04:58 (02:23)  #J189115; <04/18
>>every run      Job6      EXEC +10 16:07 (00:23)  #J189115; &0:05
                 Job7      EXEC +10 14:00 (01:02)  #J260721; <04/18
```

**Case 1 (Output): want to print only those lines where job is running from previous day. (Only second column from "EXEC" containing "/")**

```
                 Job3      EXEC +10 04/05          #J333460
                 Job4      EXEC +10 02/26 (01:10)  #J3322
```

**Case 2 (Output): want to print all lines where job is running on current day. (Second column from "EXEC" does not contain date i.e. 04/05 or 02/26)**

```
%                Job1      EXEC +10 03:28 (03:23)  #J18911
                 Job2      EXEC +10 12:56 (01:55)  #J1766
                 Job3      EXEC +10 04/05          #J333460
                 Job4      EXEC +10 02/26 (01:10)  #J3322
>>every run      Job5      EXEC +10 04:58 (02:23)  #J189115; <04/18
>>every run      Job6      EXEC +10 16:07 (00:23)  #J189115; &0:05
                 Job7      EXEC +10 14:00 (01:02)  #J260721; <04/18
```

Comment: You have tagged this with `grep`.  Did you read `man grep` or google examples? Because this is rather basic stuff (`grep 'EXEC .10 ..\/'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input file:

```
Job1      EXEC +10 03:28 (03:23)  #J18911
Job2      EXEC +10 12:56 (01:55)  #J1766
Job3      EXEC +10 04/05          #J333460
Job4      EXEC +10 02/26 (01:10)  #J3322
Job5      EXEC +10 04:58 (02:23)  #J189115; <04/18
Job6      EXEC +10 16:07 (00:23)  #J189115; &0:05
Job7      EXEC +10 14:00 (01:02)  #J260721; <04/18
```

you can use `grep` to produce the following output:

```
# Print lines with slash (/) in 4th field:
>grep 'EXEC.*/.* ' inputfile
Job3      EXEC +10 04/05          #J333460
Job4      EXEC +10 02/26 (01:10)  #J3322

# Print lines with colon (:) in 4th field
>grep 'EXEC[^(]*:.* ' inputfile
Job1      EXEC +10 03:28 (03:23)  #J18911
Job2      EXEC +10 12:56 (01:55)  #J1766
Job5      EXEC +10 04:58 (02:23)  #J189115; <04/18
Job6      EXEC +10 16:07 (00:23)  #J189115; &0:05
Job7      EXEC +10 14:00 (01:02)  #J260721; <04/18
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks Sergios